# Too many arguments to function call, expected single argument 'nums', have 3 arguments

Tags: c++

I am writing an algorithm in order to generate all permutations of an array (or a vector in the context of the provided code).

Second, this is not my code and I'm using it as a learning experience; however, I know that this is a Class that involves the "permute" member in it, and that it still needs a main function in order to be called.

My problem: I cannot find out how to call this class in a way that would take the input "(1,2,3)" and then generate the permutations. I have tried the below method as well as other ways to input the value like [1,2,3] or ({1,2,3}), but non have worked so far.

the error I get is

> Too many arguments to function call, expected single argument 'nums',
> have 3 arguments

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
class Solution
{
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > permute(std::vector<int>& nums)
    {
        if (nums.size() <= 1)
            return { nums };
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > result;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::vector<int> v(nums.begin(), nums.end());
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
            auto res = permute(v);
            for (int j = 0; j < res.size(); ++j)
            {
                std::vector<int> _v = res[j];
                _v.insert(_v.begin(), nums[j]);
                result.push_back(_v);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Solution obj;
    obj.permute(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [List initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) to create a temporary vector object. Look at `{ ... }`

Comment: Roobigol: Did any of the answers help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

- You supply 3 arguments to `permute`, but it accepts only one. Either call the function like this

  ```
  obj.permute({1, 2, 3});
  ```

  or you could add a `permute` overload that takes a parameter pack and forwards it, expanded, to your original `permute` function. The below would make it possible to call it with `obj.permute(1, 2, 3);`

  ```
  template<class... Args>
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> permute(Args&&... args) {
       return permute({std::forward<Args>(args)...});
  }
  ```
- You try to bind a non-`const` reference to the supplied temporary argument which isn't allowed. Either take it by value or make it a `const&`. A `const&` can bind to a temporary.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>   // std::forward
#include <vector>

class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> permute(const std::vector<int>& nums) {
//                                        ^^^^^
        if(nums.size() <= 1) return {nums};
        
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            std::vector<int> v(nums.begin(), nums.end());
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
            auto res = permute(v);

            for(int j = 0; j < res.size(); ++j) {
                std::vector<int> _v = res[j];
                _v.insert(_v.begin(), nums[j]);
                result.push_back(_v);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Added overload:
    template<class... Args>
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> permute(Args&&... args) {
        return permute({std::forward<Args>(args)...});
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution obj;
    auto res = obj.permute({1, 2, 3});    // note: {1,2,3}
    // auto res = obj.permute(1, 2, 3);   // would use the added overload
    for(auto& inner : res) {
        for(auto v : inner) std::cout << ' ' << v;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes the parameter as reference, so you cannot give a temporary value as parameter. The parameter is not modified, so change it to constant:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > permute(const std::vector<int>& nums)
```

After that you can call the function with a temporary value:

```
obj.permute({1, 2, 3});
```